# Child nodes not visible when setWorldOrigin is called?

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

So I have a function like below that sets the world origin to a node placed where an image is after scanning it. I load the saved nodes from a database that adds them to the scene in a separate function.

For some reason, the nodes will not show when I run the app. It works when setWorldOrigin is commented out.

I would like for the nodes to show relative to the image as the origin.

Am I missing something? Does setWorldOrigin change the session?

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
        guard let imageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor else { return }
        let referenceImage = imageAnchor.referenceImage

        let nodeGeometry = SCNText(string: "Welcome!", extrusionDepth: 1)
        nodeGeometry.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 30)
        nodeGeometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.black

        anchorNode.geometry = nodeGeometry
        anchorNode.scale = SCNVector3(0.1, 0.1, 0.1)
        anchorNode.constraints = [SCNBillboardConstraint()]
        anchorNode.position = SCNVector3(imageAnchor.transform.columns.3.x, imageAnchor.transform.columns.3.y, imageAnchor.transform.columns.3.z)
imageAnchor.transform.columns.3.y, imageAnchor.transform.columns.3.z)

        // Create a plane to visualize the initial position of the detected image.
        let plane = SCNPlane(width: referenceImage.physicalSize.width, height: referenceImage.physicalSize.height)

        let planeNode = SCNNode(geometry: plane)
        planeNode.opacity = 0.25

        /*
         * Plane is rotated to match the picture location
         */
        planeNode.eulerAngles.x = -.pi / 2

        /*
         * Scan runs as an action for a set amount of time
         */
        planeNode.runAction(self.imageHighlightAction)

        // Add the plane visualization to the scene.
        node.addChildNode(planeNode)

        sceneView.session.setWorldOrigin(relativeTransform: imageAnchor.transform)
        sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)

        /*
         * Populates the scene
         */
        handleData()
    } // renderer
```

Comment: Possible that the physicalSize is incorrect, or too small, leading to unexplained results? I would undo the opacity as well, until you are sure that you are seeing it.

Comment: What happens if you DON'T set world origin? Do the nodes get added?

Comment: @impression7vx Yes. How would I go about changing the physical size and opacity?

Comment: You are already changing the opacity with `planeNode.opacity = 0.25` -- I was just trying to say set to 1 for now so you can be sure the object is there. And I'd just print out the size. Just to make sure it's not 0 or too small. It's probably fine, just trying to rule out probabilities.

Comment: Also, idk what anchorNode is, but if you are using this elsewhere, i.e., in conjunction with other nodes, it may have an effect, since you are setting position before worldOrigin. Personally, I'd `setWorldOrigin` in the beginning -- after obtaining imageAnchor.

Comment: @impression7vx Doing those things now

Comment: @impression7vx I managed to figure it out. My image size was incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The size I had for my image was incorrect. The image I was using is 512x512 pixels. I got that by right clicking on the image and selecting "Get Info" and looking at dimensions.

I also had the measurements as meters. I changed it to centimeters and used a [pixel to centimeters converter](http://www.unitconversion.org/typography/pixels-x-to-centimeters-conversion.html)